# Taking only 1 row from a group of rows sharing the same field value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server 2008 database with records like the following

```
001 CAT 1 2 3 
002 DOG 3 3 1
003 DOG 2 1 1
004 DOG 2 1 3
005 CAT 1 3 4
```

I want to take 1 row for each unique value in column 2 (cat and dog)

so this would get me (one possible answer):

```
001 CAT 1 2 3
002 DOG 3 3 1
```

Column 1 is the PK and is a string.
Column 2 is a string

Columns 3-5 are just there to indicate there are other variable fields which I need in the final result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM YourTable t1
    JOIN 
    (SELECT MIN(Col1) AS FirstId 
     FROM YourTable GROUP BY Col2) x ON t1.Col1 = x.FirstId
```

Comment: This is really close to what I was trying - except yours is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pk, DISTINCT pet, col3, col4, col5 FROM myPetsTable
```

Would that work? Taking a shot in the dark here :)

Comment: Nope, it would bomb on the distinct.  The order matters.

Comment: As far as I know thats not valid SQL

Comment: Dr. Zim is correct - `DISTINCT` is applied to all columns in the `SELECT` clause, not selectively.

Comment: Fair enough - as I said, it was a guess :)